# WebPolicyDelegate::decidePolicyForNavigationAction How to get GET and POST data from a link clicked or form submitted?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos

I implemented a `WebPolicyDelegate` and the `...decidePolicyForNavigationAction:...` method.
It works fine, I get among other things the HTTP method [GET|POST] but what I can't find is the actual GET and POST data. Where or how should I get it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about:

```
NSString *queryString = [[request URL] query];
NSData *postData = [request HTTPBody];
```

GET data is just the query string of the URI.

Comment: Ok, so I have to parse that data? isn't there any way to get something like an NSDictionary with the GET or POST keys and their values?

Comment: For the query string, some previous responses: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3997976/parse-nsurl-query-property http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1967399/parse-nsurl-path-and-query-iphoneos http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1626876/parse-query-string-into-a-structured-nsdictionary

Comment: For post, looks like you can get the equivalent query string with `[[NSString alloc] initWithData:[request HTTPBody] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]`. See comments on the accepted answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6148900/append-data-to-a-post-nsurlrequest